# Implicitly declaring a parameter in an ASP.NET MVC action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I have this action:

```
  public ActionResult MyAction(long? personId) 
  { 
         // ...
  }
```

I can call that action with this URL:

```
  localhost/MyAction/?personId=x
```

I want to be able to send another extra parameter (`token`), which is going to be in all of my ajax calls from the client:

```
  localhost/MyAction/?personId=x&token=asdf
```

Without having to declare this new parameter in all of my action signatures. That it: I want to avoid this:

```
  public ActionResult MyAction(long? personId, string token)
  { 
         // ...
  }

  public ActionResult MyAction2(long? animalId, string token) 
  { 
         // ...
  }

  etc.
```

But I also want to be able to have access to the `token` parameter from inside the method. That is:

```
  public ActionResult MyAction(long? personId) 
  { 
         // I can check the token's value or manipulate it, eg:
         if (token.Equals(...)) { .. }
  }
```

Question:

Is there a way to declare this parameter implicitly in all (or some) of my actions? Maybe using attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could derive all your controllers from a common base controller.
Then, override OnActionExecuting in that and access the Querystring. For example:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected string Token { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        string token = Request.QueryString["token"] as string;
        Token = token ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I find that a cleaner solution than a static class. Also, the BaseController is a useful pattern in MVC to share code that is used in many controllers.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Token
{
  public static string Value
  {
    get
    {
      return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["token"];
    }
  }
}

public ActionResult MyAction(long? personId) 
{ 
  // I can check the token's value or manipulate it, eg:
  if (Token.Value.Equals(...)) { .. }
}
```

Do not forget to account for `Token.Value` being `null`.